# The difference area between two regions

Tags: polynomials, computational-geometry

I have two polygons `poly1` and `poly0`, I need the difference area of them. Below is my trial:

```
poly0 = Import["t0.txt", "Data"]
poly1 = Import["t1.txt", "Data"]

Graphics[{Red, Polygon@poly0 , Green, Polygon@poly1}]
```

[image]

```
RegionDifference[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Polygon@poly1], 
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Polygon@poly0]]
```

[image]

Obviously, the `RegionDifference` cannot work normally.

[image]

**data**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6inghzi80uembji/t0.txt?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2j0iui9alzwdsm/t1.txt?dl=0

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some old definitions? Try clearing all global variables or quitting the kernel. I have no problem with getting the `RegionMeasure` of `RegionMeasure` as in your post, as well as in Mauricio's answer.

Comment: @corey979 Yes, In addtion, I guess your Mathematica version is V11.0.1, rather than 10.4 or 11.0.0

Comment: No, I'm on `10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `DiscretizeRegion` first

```
r1 = DiscretizeRegion@Polygon@poly0;
r2 = DiscretizeRegion@Polygon@poly1;
rd = RegionDifference[r2, r1]
RegionMeasure@rd
```

[image]

Comment: I got this https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHfE5.png in Mma 10.4

Comment: hmmm .... weird .... I am using Mathematica 11. Perhaps there were some problems with `RegionDifference` in 10.4. Sorry, no idea in that case

Comment: That's all right:) Mma 11 also fails to return the result you give.

Comment: What?? In Mma 11 it does not work for you? Did you just copy paste the code I posted? It should work with Mma 11.

Comment: Yes, here is the snapshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFm4r.png

Comment: 11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (July 28, 2016)

Comment: I am using 11.0.1 for Windows. Download this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HppN1nEJ6KNXBoM2R1b2Z5YVU/view?usp=sharing , extract the notebook and the data, run the notebook and if it does not work, then it might be a version problem.

Comment: Anyway, thanks very much!